# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::links()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pagination, paginator

whats up ?
I have a little problem with Laravel Paginator.

I built the function using order by and paginator, but I'm getting the error message "Call to undefined method Illuminate \ Database \ Query \ Builder :: links () (View: C: \ wamp \ www \ laravel \ app \ views \ frontend \ premios.blade.php). "

============= My Function ==============

```
public function premios()
{
$this->layout->content = View::make('frontend.premios')->with('premiostexto',PremiosTexto::all()) ->with('premios', Premios::orderBy('ordem', 'ASC')->paginate(5));
}
```

==========My View============

```
@foreach($premios as $premios)
    <span class="tituloPremio">{{$premios->titulo}}</span>
    <span class="dataPremio">{{$premios->data}}</span>
@endforeach

    {{ $premios->links() }}
```

I tried putting "$premios->links()" inside and outside the foreach.Without pagination everything works good

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are overriding the `$premios` variable in the `foreach`. Use it as singular form in the `foreach`:

```
@foreach($premios as $premio)
    <span class="tituloPremio">{{$premio->titulo}}</span>
    <span class="dataPremio">{{$premio->data}}</span>
@endforeach

{{ $premios->links() }}
```

Comment: it's working awesome. very usefull. Thank you very much.